# Selenium: Selecting Items from a List with No IDs

Tags: python, selenium

I'm experimenting with python + selenium, but I'm having trouble navigating list items when there is no ID provided for the elements.

In short, the page I'm interested in contains a list with two elements (see below): "Pitch View" and "List View". By default, "Pitch View" is selected, but I need the list view.

```
    <div class="sc-bdnxRM ichxnR">
      <div>
        <ul class="Tabs__TabList-sc-1e6ubpf-0 eSBWKp">   [flex]
          <li class="Tab__Item-sc-19t48gi-0 bsocgQ">
             ::marker
             <a class="Tab__Link-sc-19t48gi-1 dDKNAk" href="#pitch">Pitch View></a> [event]
          </li>
          <li class="Tab__Item-sc-19t48gi-0 bsocgQ">
             ::marker
             <a class="Tab__Link-sc-19t48gi-1 xSQCR" href="#list">List View></a> [event]
          </li>
        </ul>

 ...
```

Sorry, a screen shot would have been cleaner, but I don't seem to have permission.

I can load up the page, and I'm able to interact with all the elements. Switching to the "List View" manually is not an issue once that's done, but I can't seem to get Selenium to change to the view automatically. I'm getting TimeoutException errors, but the real issue is that I'm not providing the right element tags, so Selenium can't navigate correctly. Most of my attempts have been variations on the code shown below.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//a[@class='Tab__Link-sc-19t48gi-1 xSQCR']")))
    element.click()
```

If I can get to the "List View", I'll be fine from there as retrieving data from the tables isn't a problem once they are rendered.

My background isn't in web programming, so apologies if this is a simple question. If anyone is able to assist, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

**Update:**

It took a bit of tweaking, but I did eventually get it to work after exploring the link provided by Ahmed. Examples below using both the absolute as well as relative xpaths in case anyone else is stuck on this:

Absolute path

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
```

Relative Path

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"#list")]').click()
```

Thanks to both Ahmed and Dan.

Comment: This `Tab__Link-sc-19t48gi-1 xSQCR` seems like a dynamic class name that changes between each time you open the website, try searching for the element using it's text "List View" which can be done using `xpath` and `contains()`

Comment: Use this xpath `'//a[href="#list"]'` to select it, see [here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the href and get the results you want.

```
[href=‘#list’]
```